# CodeIgniter fresh copy works over LAN, but gets 403 over WAN

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-403

I'm starting a new CodeIgniter project, so I grabbed a fresh copy of version 2.1, and unarchived it to my local Apache root. I set up config.php and tested the site from localhost and another machine via the computer's LAN IP, and it worked as expected.

I also have my router forward WAN port 443 to port 80 on my server machine, so that I can access my Apache server from school (via wan_ip:443). This usually works fine, but when I try access my new CodeIgniter copy, I get a 403 Forbidden page.

I can still access all other sub-folders on my Apache server via WAN, including other, older, CodeIgniter projects.

There is no .htaccess file in the root of the fresh copy. I tried chmod-ing 755 and 777 recursively, but with no change.

Anybody have any idea what could be causing this? I've done quite a few CodeIgniter projects, and I've never had this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an Apache issue. I created an .htaccess file and added "Allow from all" to it, and now it works. I'm not sure why I needed to do that since I could access all my other Apache directories over WAN just fine, but it worked.

Comment: If that's the answer to your question, then you should accept it. It's ok to accept your own answer if it's the right one.

Comment: @YoavAner I will, but because I'm a noobie on here it won't let me to do that for another day

Comment: @FelixMc You could be a god here and you would still need to wait two days. So don't worry, that's not your fold ;)

Comment: you should also config codeigniter base_url to the local ip, other wise all your links will break

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at the apache config maybe there is something related to the ip.

Also check your codeigniter config. Maybe it is doing some routing.

Try to replace your project with a simple index.html if that works apache is fine.

Check if your project itself does some redirect or something like this...

Comment: thanks for the feedback!
by testing out the index.php file I was able to figure out it was an Apache issue, see my answer to this question below